# Storing a dataframe in dictionary, weird output in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a function that returns a dataframe to my main. I am trying to store these dataframes in a dictionary, in order to retrieve them again later.

When I run this:

```
sa_wp5 = get_SA_WP5_value('testfile.txt')
template_dict["SAWP5Country Name"] = sa_wp5
```

my output looks like the following:

```
{'SAWP5Country Name':            1    2
0  Australia  047}
```

where I would rather the output just be the variable itself containing the dataframe.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this is not a complete post, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to improve the quality of your post (and receive help faster)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong here. Just a matter of formatting due to the default `__str__()` output of a DataFrame object. If you feel messy, try this way to print out your dict:

```
for key, df in template_dict.items():
    print("%s:" % key)
    print(df.to_string())
    print("-------")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bunch to store all sorts of objects for easy retrieval.

```
from sklearn.datasets.base import Bunch
```

Then create a variable using the Bunch() method:

```
a = Bunch(df1 = df_template.copy(), df2 = df_other_df.copy())
```

Then you can simply call them as such:

```
a.df1
a.df1['col1']
df = a.df2
```

etc.

It's really effective for storage of objects.